# Stabilizing conjugacy classes of integer matrices

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Conj}{Conj} \DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id} \newcommand\Z{\mathbb{Z}}$

For an $n \times n$ integer matrix $A \in \GL_n(\Z)$, let $\Conj(A)$
be the set of $n \times n$ integer matrices that are
$\GL_n(\Z)$-conjugate to $A$.  Also, let $A \oplus \id_m$ be the
$(n+m) \times (n+m)$ integer matrix obtained by adjoining an $m \times
m$ identity matrix to the bottom right hand corner of $A$.

**Question**: There is a natural map $\Conj(A) \rightarrow \Conj(A
\oplus \id_m)$.  Are there conditions on $A$ that ensure this is
always a surjection/injection/bijection?  Also, is it the case that
for sufficiently large $m$ we always have that the map $\Conj(A \oplus
\id_m) \rightarrow \Conj(A \oplus \id_{m+1})$ is a bijection?

Comment: The natural map $X \rightarrow X \oplus \mathrm{id}_m$ is always an injection. It is a bijection if and only if $A=\mathrm{id}_n$ since $\mathrm{id}_m \oplus A$ belongs to $\mathrm{Conj}(A \oplus \mathrm{id}_m)$ by perturbation.

Comment: Shoot, I stated this incorrectly, and as you point out it is obviously false.  I'd delete it, but there is no button for me to do that.

Comment: Related question: If $A \oplus \operatorname{id}_m$ is conjugate to $B \oplus \operatorname{id}_m$, does it then follow that $A$ is conjugate to $B$?

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Versions of that were what I really meant to ask about, but I totally screwed it up when writing the question.  I'll probably ask a corrected question in a few days, but I don't want to spam MO with constant variants on the same thing.

Comment: Actually, I can answer this one too now: The $2\times 2$-matrix $A := \begin{pmatrix} 8 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb Z^{2\times 2}$ is not similar to its transpose $A^T$ (this was claimed in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1732276/ and can be easily checked solving the relevant system by hand), but the $3\times 3$-matrix $A \oplus \operatorname{id}_1$ is similar to $A^T \oplus \operatorname{id}_1$ via the invertible conjugating matrix $M = \begin{pmatrix} 1&-4&2 \\ -4&14&-7 \\ 2&-7&3 \end{pmatrix} \in \operatorname{GL}_3\left(\mathbb Z\right)$ (just ...

Comment: ... check that $\det M = 1$ and $\left(A \oplus \operatorname{id}_1\right) M = M \left(A^T \oplus \operatorname{id}_1\right)$). See also the Example on page 15 of https://web.archive.org/web/20141004072809/http://hermite.cii.fc.ul.pt/elc/meetings/im_1997/lectures.pdf ("Direct sums") for a counterexample to a similar question.

Comment: Neat example @darijgrinberg! Do you know if $A$ and $A^T$ are always conjugate after some stabilization?

Comment: @Nate: I don't know; the counterexample was just a guess that turned out right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

${\rm Conj}(A)\to{\rm Conj}(A\oplus I_m)$ is not surjective, because
$$I_m\oplus A\in{\rm Conj}(A\oplus I_m) \quad\hbox{but}\quad\not\in R({\rm Conj}(A)).$$